# Como insertar datos de una tabla seleccionando datos de otra tabla mysql

Tags: php, mysql

**tengo el siguiente codigo:**

```
if($_POST['id']=="id")
{ 

$nomb_idm=$_POST['nombre'];
$n_idm=$_POST['id'];
$nivel_ide=$_POST['nivel'];
$pass_ide=$_POST['pass'];
$correo_idm= $_POST['correo']; 
$usuario_ide= $_POST['usuario']; 

$idfto=$_POST['id'];
$ide_consult = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id=".$idfto."" ;
$ide_result = $conexion->query($ide_consult);
while( $ide_fila = $ide_result->fetch_array() )
 { $idm=$ide_fila['id_foto'];}

if($idfto===$idm){
    $msj="El usuario existe , crear con un numero de registro diferente o borrar el existente";
    header("Location: index.php?msj=".$msj."");

}else{


$ide_permisos = "INSERT INTO permisos(id, nivel, smenu, status) 
SELECT permisos_default.nivel,permisos_default.smenu,permisos_default.status 
FROM permisos_default 
WHERE permisos_default.nivel LIKE '%{$nivel_ide}%'";
$ide_p_result = $conexion->query($ide_permisos);




$msj="Usuario Creado con Exito";
header("Location: index.php?msj=".$msj.""); 

}


}
```

Con este codigo lo que hago es que al enviatr el id del usuario uso el mismo para signar permisos a una tabla que le llamo permisos, pero tomando de la tabla permisos_default por medio del nivel del usuario.

El codigo me inserta el usuario pero no me inserta los permisos en la tabla permisos.

**Mi problema incide en este codigo:**

```
$ide_permisos = "INSERT INTO permisos(id, nivel, smenu, status) 
SELECT permisos_default.nivel,permisos_default.smenu,permisos_default.status 
FROM permisos_default 
WHERE permisos_default.nivel LIKE '%{$nivel_ide}%'";
$ide_p_result = $conexion->query($ide_permisos);
```

Alguna sugerencia o ayuda por favor

Muchas Gracias.!

Comment: Algo que se ve extraño en la consulta es que intentas insertar en el campo `id` de la tabla `permisos` el valor del campo `nivel` de la tabla `permisos_default` y haces un `LIKE` sobre ese mismo campo como si éste fuese del tipo String y no numérico. ¿De qué tipo es el campo `id` en la tabla del INSERT y de qué tipo es el campo `nivel` en la tabla del SELECT? También, asegúrate que hay un espacio entre `)` y `SELECT ...` e igualmente en cada salto de línea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que sufres es que no estás agregando el `id` del usuario a la consulta:

```
$ide_permisos = "
  INSERT INTO permisos (
    id,
    nivel,
    smenu,
    status
  )
  SELECT
    {$idfto} id,
    nivel,
    smenu,
    status
  FROM permisos_default 
  WHERE nivel LIKE '%{$nivel_ide}%'
";
```

De esta manera se copiará cada elemento de la plantilla del nivel que tienes en `permisos_default` en `permisos` usando la `id` del usuario deseado. El alias `id` no es necesario, pero te será útil para depurar dónde debe ir cada valor o a qué se refiere ese número.

Ejemplo online: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ihomAdT8uTaUrjAvr6oAhG/0

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia por tus recomendaciones , eso me funciono excelente

Answer (score 0):

Veamos aparte cada instrucción:

```
INSERT INTO permisos(
      id, 
      nivel, 
      smenu, 
      status) 

SELECT 
      permisos_default.nivel,
      permisos_default.smenu,
      permisos_default.status 

FROM permisos_default 
WHERE permisos_default.nivel LIKE '%{$nivel_ide}%'
```

El `INSERT` tiene indicadas **cuatro columnas**, mientras que en el `SELECT` estás seleccionando **sólo tres**. La consulta no funcionará de ese modo. Si `id` es del tipo `AUTO_INCREMENT` o `SERIAL` puedes omitirlo en el `INSERT`.

También es importante tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

- Debe haber en el `SELECT` tantas columnas como en el `INSERT`
- Los tipos de dato de cada columna deben coincidir
- El código podría fallar en casos de intentos de `INSERT` que creasen filas duplicadas
- El `INSERT` no se efectuará si no hay nada en el `SELECT`, es decir, si no se cumplen las condiciones del `WHERE`.

Son cosas a tomar en cuenta.

---

Nota:

Si la variable que pasas en el `LIKE` proviene de una fuente externa (formulario u otro), tu código es vulnerable a la Inyección SQL. Se recomienda vivamente usar consultas preparadas para evitarlo.